# MNIST number guesser stuck at 9.84% accuracy

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, mnist

I built a MNIST dataset through watching yt tutorials. Every tutorial was using numpy but since pytorch is a newer technology I decided to build mine using pytorch. The problem is that my model is stuck at 9.84% accuracy, which means it is guessing randomly.

What could be wrong that causes this inaccuracy?

Output after 5 epochs:

```
Acc: 9.84%
Acc: 9.84%
Acc: 9.84%
Acc: 9.84%
Acc: 9.84%
```

My code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd

"""
w = weights, b = bias, i = input, h = hidden, o = output, l = label
e.g. w_i_h = weights from input layer to hidden layer
"""
"""
w = weights, b = bias, i = input, h = hidden, o = output, l = label
e.g. w_i_h = weights from input layer to hidden layer
"""

# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame, considering the first row as column labels
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0)

# Convert the label and pixel columns to a PyTorch tensor
labels = torch.tensor(data['label'].values)
labels = labels.view(-1, 1)
labels = F.one_hot(labels.squeeze(), num_classes=10) # onehot the labels
images = torch.tensor(data.iloc[:, 1:].values)

train_images = images[:, :40000] 
test_images = images[:, 40000:42000]

# divide the rgb coding to probabilities
# 1 = black, 0 = white
train_images = train_images.float() / 255
test_images = test_images.float() / 255

# w_i_h = weights from input layer to hidden layer
w_i_h = torch.rand(10, 784) - 0.5

# b_i_h = biases from input layer to hidden layer
b_i_h = torch.zeros(10, 1)

# w_h_o = weights from hidden layer to output layer
w_h_o = torch.rand(10, 10) - 0.5

# b_h_o = biases from hidden layer to output layer
b_h_o = torch.zeros(10, 1)  

epochs = 1
learn_rate = 0.01

epochs = 1
learn_rate = 0.1

for epoch in range(epochs):
    nr_correct = 0
    for i, l in zip(train_images, labels):
        # make then image from column of 784 to matrix of size (784, 1)
        i = i.view(784, 1)
        l = l.view(10, 1)
        
        # forward propagation
        # input layer -> hidden layer        
        z1 = w_i_h @ i + b_i_h
        relu = torch.nn.ReLU() # because you can't call it directly
        a1 = relu(z1)

        # hidden layer -> output layer
        z2 = w_h_o @ a1 + b_h_o
        a2 = F.softmax(z2, dim=1) # dim=0 specifies that we soft max along columns / from top to bottom

        # error / cost calculation
        cost = 1 / len(l) * torch.sum((a2 - l) ** 2)

        # check if the biggest output prediction matches the correct label
        nr_correct += int(torch.argmax(a2) == torch.argmax(l))
        
        # backward propagation
        # output layer -> hidden layer
        o_err = a2 - l
        w_h_o = -learn_rate * o_err @ a1.T
        b_h_o = -learn_rate * o_err

        # hidden layer -> input layer
        h_err = w_h_o.mm(o_err) * (a1 > 0)
        w_i_h = -learn_rate * h_err @ i.T
        b_i_h = -learn_rate * h_err

    # Show accuracy for this epoch
    print(f"Acc: {round((nr_correct / len(labels)) * 100, 2)}%")
```

The code from the tutorial:

```
from data import get_mnist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


"""
w = weights, b = bias, i = input, h = hidden, o = output, l = label
e.g. w_i_h = weights from input layer to hidden layer
"""
images, labels = get_mnist()
w_i_h = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (20, 784))
w_h_o = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (10, 20))
b_i_h = np.zeros((20, 1))
b_h_o = np.zeros((10, 1))

learn_rate = 0.01
nr_correct = 0
epochs = 1
for epoch in range(epochs): # 5
    for img, l in zip(images, labels):
        img.shape += (1,)
        l.shape += (1,)

        # Forward propagation input -> hidden
        h_pre = b_i_h + w_i_h @ img
        h = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-h_pre))
        print(img)

        # Forward propagation hidden -> output
        o_pre = b_h_o + w_h_o @ h
        o = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-o_pre))

        # Cost / Error calculation
        e = 1 / len(o) * np.sum((o - l) ** 2, axis=0)
        nr_correct += int(np.argmax(o) == np.argmax(l))
        
        # Backpropagation output -> hidden (cost function derivative)
        delta_o = o - l
        w_h_o += -learn_rate * delta_o @ np.transpose(h)
        b_h_o += -learn_rate * delta_o
        # Backpropagation hidden -> input (activation function derivative)
        delta_h = np.transpose(w_h_o) @ delta_o * (h * (1 - h))
        w_i_h += -learn_rate * delta_h @ np.transpose(img)
        b_i_h += -learn_rate * delta_h
        break
    # Show accuracy for this epoch
    print(f"Acc: {round((nr_correct / images.shape[0]) * 100, 2)}%")
    nr_correct = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is whenever you're backpropagating your error, you end up replacing the weights and biases instead of adjusting them. You are replacing it by using '=' instead of '-=' Here is an how you can fix it:

```
# backward propagation
# output layer -> hidden layer
o_err = a2 - l
w_h_o -= learn_rate * o_err @ a1.T
b_h_o -= learn_rate * o_err

# hidden layer -> input layer
h_err = w_h_o.T @ o_err * (a1 > 0)
w_i_h -= learn_rate * h_err @ i.T
b_i_h -= learn_rate * h_err
```

You should also play around with the loss function, you're using a mean squared error loss with a softmax output layer, which is typically not the best choice for a multiclass classification problem like MNIST so you should probably look at cross entropy loss instead. Hope this helps!